# Treeview parent nodes duplicating

Tags: c#, vb.net, treeview

I wanted to know how to see if the parent nodes are duplicating and if they are I want to remove them. I am using a button in Visual Studio to call the code 
`string k = Convert.ToString(IM + 1);
treeView1.Nodes.Add(k);`

IM is just basically an integer with -1 value. Is it possible to detect similar nodes ? As i previously mentioned there are no child nodes, only parent nodes.
In a nutshell if I add the nodes I get 1, 1, 1, and I can keep going, but I want to make it so that I can only add one 1, and one 2 and so on. 
Thank you for anything!

Comment: More than an hour ago and no answers :( I guess it is hopeless.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an example of how you can find nodes in a TreeView

```
private void addNodes()
    {
        try
        {
            TestTreeView.Nodes.Clear();

            for (int counter = 1; counter <= 10; counter++)
            {
                TreeNode[] nodes = TestTreeView.Nodes.Find(counter.ToString(), true);
                if (nodes.Length == 0)
                {
                    TestTreeView.Nodes.Add(counter.ToString(), counter.ToString());
                }
                else
                {
                    //node exists
                }
            }

            for (int counter = 5; counter <= 15; counter++)
            {
                TreeNode[] nodes = TestTreeView.Nodes.Find(counter.ToString(), true);
                if (nodes.Length == 0)
                {
                    TestTreeView.Nodes.Add(counter.ToString(), counter.ToString());
                }
                else
                {
                    //node exists
                }
            }

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(string.Concat("An error occurred: ", ex.Message));
        }

    }
```

Comment: Sadly this solution is in Visual Basic, so it is very hard for me to translate properly, can you maybe translate the key functions, so I can somehow make it work ?

Comment: Yes, I edited the code, so it would work for my case and it did wonders :) Thanks!